# How to creat printf with slightly different name

Tags: serial-port, printf, avr, stdio, usart

I am using ATmega128 and I need two serial ports for communication. I have been using printf from "stdio.h" header file to send data through USART 0. I also need to send data through USART 1 to lcd and I am curious about using formatted input function. I have been thinking that connecting same printf function to USART 1 and USART 0 makes the compiler confused so I haven't tried it.

Can anyone suggest how to make another printf say "Lprintf" to send data through USART 1 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do here is to use `fprintf()`. See the documentation on avr-libc for the function. Essentially, you want to have a `fputc()` function for UART1 and one for UART0. Then, based on that, you can create two `FILE` buffers. Once you do so, you are free to use `fprintf()` on each. Optionally, you can point `stdout` to one of these buffers, as to be able to use `printf()`.

```
FILE uart1_out = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart1_putc, 0, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
FILE uart0_out = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart0_putc, 0, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

fprintf(&uart1_out, "printing to UART1");
fprintf(&uart0_out, "printing %d to UART0", 0);

stdout = &uart1_out;
stderr = &uart0_out;

printf("This string will be printed thru UART1");
fprintf(stderr, "This string will be printed thru UART0");
```

You just need to provide the implementation for `int uart1_putc(int, FILE*)` and `int uart0_putc(int, FILE*)` to manipulate data as you wish.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've linked it, there are two alternatives that are possibly simpler:

1. Use [`sprintf()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga6017094d9fd800fa02600d35399f2a2a) to write your formatted text to a string, and then use your own `putchar()` or `putstring()` to send it to the desired USART.
2. If you're using the [`FILE`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga3e8cefeee58f762ff50bcef35fa12eec) struct to link your USARTs to the stdio functions (likely), you can use [`fprintf()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#ga0e41285401c397eb29692205a95fcd9c) to direct the results to a particular stream.